# CentOS 6.5 hostname on VPS

Tags: centos, hostname, hosts, vps

I'm trying to change the hostname on my fresh CentOS 6.5 image (VPS) via SSH. The sources I've found all say the hostname can be permanently changed in `/etc/sysconfig/network` and `/etc/hosts`, and that the current hostname can be checked using the `hostname` command. The problem, however, is that the `hostname` command doesn't return anything shown in either of the two aforementioned files. For clarity, in the following commands the following information has been substituted: `username` (obvious), `curHN` is what is *currently* reported after the `@` sign in my SSH prompt, `provider.com` is my VPS provider's website.

What would be the correct way of changing the hostname on this setup?

```
[username@curHN ~]$ hostname
curHN.provider.com

[username@curHN ~]$ cat /etc/sysconfig/network
NETWORKING=yes
HOSTNAME=localhost.localdomain

[username@curHN ~]$ cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
```

Answer (score 0):

You've mentioned all of the pieces to change it. Use the hostname command with the new hostname as an argument (Your current shell won't reflect the change; log out and back in again), set the hostname parameter in /etc/sysconfig/network for reboot persistence, and then make sure that /etc/hosts has a line to match the IP to the new hostname for local hostname resolution.

https://serverfault.com/questions/369415/configure-domain-name-in-centos

Answer (score 0):

Edit simple /etc/sysconfig/network and put hostname fqdn
then edit /etc/hostname and put hostname fqdn
then edit /etc/hosts.
For example,your hostname fqdn is linux.feel.good and
ip is 1.2.4.5
so
/etc/sysconfig/network

```
HOSTNAME=linux.feel.good
```

/etc/hostname (can be also /etc/HOSTNAME)

```
linux.feel.good
```

and /etc/hosts

```
1.2.4.5  linux.feel.good  linux
```